# C weird behavior when dividing two floats

Tags: c, arduino, esp32

I have some code that I run on an ESP32 written in Arduino. The problem is that my result is rounded up when it should not be.

```
float step_value = (float)abs(levels_values[i] - levels_values[i - 1]) / abs(levels_percentages[i] - levels_percentages[i - 1]);
float percentage_diff = (float)abs(current_value - levels_values[i - 1]) / step_value;

Serial.println(step_value);   
Serial.println(2.00/step_value);
Serial.println(2.00/0.07);
```

And inside the console the output is:

```
0.07
30.00
28.57
```

Why is that if I divide by the variable, I get a rounded value and when I divide by the value of the variable I get the right value.

**levels_values** and **levels_percentages** vectors are of type **int**

Comment: What do you get with `Serial.println(2.00/0.07f);`? (Note the `f` at the end of `0.07`.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What are the values of all input variables used in the calculation?

Comment: What do you get with `step_value = 0.07;  
Serial.println(2.00/step_value);` ?

Comment: By default, `println` will only print two digits after the decimal point. You should request more, e.g. `Serial.println(step_value, 6)`, and see what the output is.

Comment: I'm guessing the *actual* value of `step_value` is `0.06666666667`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `step_value` is about .0666667. `Serial.println(step_value)` is not printing the complete value; it is rounding it to two decimal digits after the decimal point.

`Serial.println(2.00/step_value)` prints “30.00” because 2.00/.0666667 is about 30.

`Serial.println(2.00/0.07)` prints “28.57” because 2.00/.07 is about 28.57.

Comment: OK, then I need to set a bigger precision on the variable step_value?
Here is the full code https://gist.github.com/GeoPablo/4815cbf7baf21928b87e47c739a35147

Comment: @GeorgianStan Nobody here wants to visit your github to offer an answer.